# Problems w/XML Parser for iOS

Tags: xml, ios, xml-parsing

Hey guys (and gals), I'm currently working on a relatively simple iPhone app which pulls records from a database.

I'm trying to use NSXMLParser to do it, but for some reason, after reaching the 10th element, the entire app just decides to up and quit. I'm not quite sure why this happens. We aren't given any errors by the log. It just stops.

I've included the didStartElement and didEndElements that we've got.

didStartelement

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSMutableString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
//NSLog(@"elementName = %@", elementName);
txt = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//curElem = elementName;
//currentRestaurant = [[Restaurant alloc] init];


if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"]){
    curElem = elementName;
    currentRestaurant = [[Restaurant alloc] init];

    return;
}

else {
    curElem = nil;
}
```

and didEndElement

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
//if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"] ) {
    // Do something here
    //NSLog(@"TXT: %@", txt);

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"RestID"]){
        currentRestaurant.RestID = [txt integerValue];
        NSLog(@"RestID: %@", currentRestaurant.RestID);

    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"]) {
        currentRestaurant.Name = txt;
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", currentRestaurant.Name);
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Address"]){
        currentRestaurant.Address = txt;
        NSLog(@"Address: %@", currentRestaurant.Address);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Phone"]){
        currentRestaurant.Phone = txt;
        NSLog(@"Phone: %@", currentRestaurant.Phone);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NumNoms"]){
        currentRestaurant.NumNoms = [txt integerValue];
        NSLog(@"NumNoms: %@", currentRestaurant.NumNoms);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"PriceID"]){
        currentRestaurant.PriceID = [txt integerValue];
        NSLog(@"PriceID: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentRestaurant.PriceID]);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"OpenTime"]){
        currentRestaurant.OpenTime = txt;
        NSLog(@"OpenTime: %@", currentRestaurant.OpenTime);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CloseTime"]){
        currentRestaurant.CloseTime = txt;
        NSLog(@"CloseTime: %@", currentRestaurant.CloseTime);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"TypeID"]){
        currentRestaurant.OpenTime = txt;
        NSLog(@"TypeID: %@", currentRestaurant.TypeID);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"imgURL"]){
        currentRestaurant.imgURL = txt;
        NSLog(@"imgURL: %@", currentRestaurant.imgURL);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Coupons"]){
        //currentRestaurant.Coupons = txt;
        //NSLog(@"Coupons: %@", currentRestaurant.Coupons);


    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Specials"]){
        currentRestaurant.Specials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [txt integerValue]];
        NSLog(@"Specials: %@", currentRestaurant.Specials);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Flagged"]){
        currentRestaurant.Flagged = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [txt integerValue]];
        NSLog(@"Flagged: %@", currentRestaurant.Flagged);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"timesFlagged"]){
        currentRestaurant.timesFlagged = [txt integerValue];
        NSLog(@"timesFlagged: %@", currentRestaurant.timesFlagged);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Delivery"]){
        currentRestaurant.Delivery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [txt integerValue]];
        NSLog(@"Delivery: %@", currentRestaurant.Delivery);

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"TigerBucks"]){
        currentRestaurant.TigerBucks = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [txt integerValue]];
        NSLog(@"TigerBucks: %@", currentRestaurant.TigerBucks);
        [xmlData addObject:currentRestaurant];
        [currentRestaurant dealloc];
    }


    //NSLog(@"Current Rest name: %@", currentRestaurant.Name);
    //[xmlData addObject:currentRestaurant];
    for (id obj in xmlData)
        NSLog(@"A record in xmlData: %@", obj);
    [objArray addObject:txt];
    //NSLog(@"objArray: %@", [objArray count]);
    //NSLog(@"xmlData: %@", [xmlData count]);
    [txt release];

    return;
//}
[txt release];
txt = nil;
//NSLog(@"objArray: %@", [objArray count]);
//NSLog(@"xmlData: %@", [xmlData count]);
```

}

Again, any and all advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your sample XML also?

Comment: So we ended up tinkering and figuring out why the app was crashing. Only issue is, now I've got another issue with not being able to verify if the parsed array is getting returned correctly. Oh dear....

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [TouchXML](http://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML).

It is very easy to use and has not caused me any problems.